# Rendering 2 components in one cell renderer

Tags: components, angular5, rendering, ag-grid

I want to render 2 components in one cell renderer using ag-grid in angular5, so that both have same set of params passed to them. Is it possible?﻿ Sorry if the question is not clear. Im new to programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible by doing this trick:
Create one cell renderer that will act as a wrap for other n components.This cell renderer will take the params and share those with the other n components.
[image]

[image]

and the component html that looks like this:
[image]

Mine uses just one component